# How to change arrows size

Tags: css, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using a Bootstrap datepicker and I changed its size as it was far too small.
I used the following css:

```
.ui-datepicker.ui-widget.ui-widget-content{
    font-size: 45px !important;
    max-height: fit-content !important;
  }
```

However, now the arrows to change the month are far too small compared to everything else of the widget.

[image]

My problem is that I do not manage to change the size. I tried changing the `width` and `height` of `ui-icon` as follows.

```
.ui-icon{
    width: 32px //double than before
    height: 32px //double than before
}
```

but it just shows more icons:

[image]

Surprisingly, I was not able to find any similar topic.

Any help?

Comment: Is there anything helpful in this SO Question? >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571463/bootstrap-navigation-arrows-missing-for-datepicker

Comment: Not really. I already tried it, but I guess it is a different problem. I do see the icons, only that they are too small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This widget seems to use all icons as a css sprite (link here: https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png) - so all icons are placed in one large image grid and icon is determined by `background-position` property, which only shows a clipped icon that is required. Changing `font-size`, `background-size` won't help. You'd need to use little math and with each `width`/`height` change recalculate the scaled coordinates of the sprited icon (correct `background-size` and `background-position` to fit the icon precisely. That's imho a waste of time and I'd use some different icon, either an image, or background image or a font icon

Comment: this is where I think the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571463/bootstrap-navigation-arrows-missing-for-datepicker will be a help _ It replaces the UI icons with Font-Awesome

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That was exactly the problem. :)
In order to replace the image, some proposals did not work for me, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47839664/5802289) did.

Answer (score 0):

I think here 'font-size' problem. Check the arrows font size from inspect mode and Increse the font size.

Comment: The arrow is a background image, not a text. Changing font-size does nothing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If the arrow is an image then you can set the width of the image higher.

```
.ui-datepicker.ui-widget.ui-widget-content img{
width: suitable width;
  }
```

Hope that helps you answer your query

Comment: I had already tried this. I have expanded a bit more on the question to explain it more clearly.